# Migrate analytics data from Webtrekk to Adobe Analytics

Tags: web-analytics, adobe-analytics

As a premise... I'm definitely not an analytics expert, so I might be going in the wrong way. Let me know if my question just doesn't make sense :)

A customer is currently using WebTrekk to collect marketing data. They just bought Adobe Analytics, and we have to activate it by the end of may.
They asked us to import data for the initial months of 2015 from webtrekk to Adobe, because they want to have the data for the whole year.

Now, I've found a way (Data Sources) to send batch data to Adobe Analytics. I've *not* found a way to download "raw" data (i.e. not aggregated in reports) from WebTrekk.

Do you know if there is a way to download such data? Or could you suggest me the correct way to handle this kind of situations?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of exporting data from Webtrekk, but the kind of raw data export you're asking about has to be enabled in the account. You should check with the representative that manages your customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Full Processing Data Sources to import data in Adobe Analytics. Contact WebTrekk to get the old log file (hit data) and import it into Adobe Analytics through Full processing Data Sources.